# Unknown packages after updating meteor: how to resolve

Tags: meteor, package

I have installed a new ubuntu machine and imported my meteor app from bitbucket. However when I try running the app the following error occurs:

```
unknown package: accounts-admin-ui
```

The meteor version on my new machine is 1.0.4.1. On the old machine it is 1.0.3. On the old machine the app is running perfectly.

I tried the following things

```
meteor add mrt:accounts-admin-ui
meteor add kenyee:meteor-accounts-admin-ui
```

I even tried:

```
meteor remove accounts-admin-ui
```

Nothing helps so I tried:

```
mrt migrate-app
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens after that.

I have the same problem with the package stale-session. The only things that helps is removing the package definitions in the file ./meteor/packages. But this is not the solution I want because my app needs these packages.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with bitbucket. Do you have SSH access there or even root rights? In that case you can copy that package from bitbucket (it probably is located in `/user/.meteor/packages` or `/user/.meteorite/packages`) and put in your apps packages folder which always has priority (`/yourMeteorAppDir/packages`). Not the nicest way but it could work...

Comment: @JeyDWork is giving you your only solution I think. The package is no longer hosted in atmosphere. You have likely had that package forever and it hasn't been an issue until you tried to migrate hosts now. Closest package available is: https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3

Comment: Thank you for the information guys. Im afraid you are right. I tried to copy the package to the folder /myApp/packages but is doesnt work. Is there something extra I have to do in my package definition to make it work?